# Integrate GreenDao with Retrofit

Tags: java, android, retrofit, greendao

I'm searching for a solution that allows me to getting work retrofit and GreenDao together.

This is my code and does not work.

Post is a class generated by greenDao generator

EDIT: the run of this code returns me "retrofit.RetrofitError: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $
"

```
public static void test() {
    RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
            .setEndpoint(BASE_URL)
            .build();

    PostsInterface postsInterface = restAdapter.create(PostsInterface.class);

    Callback<List<Post>> callback = new Callback<List<Post>>() {
        @Override
        public void success(List<Post> posts, Response response) {
            Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
            Log.d(TAG, error.toString());
        }
    };

    postsInterface.getPosts(0, 10, callback);
}

public interface PostsInterface {
    @GET("/posts")
    void getPosts(@Query("start") int limit, @Query("count") int offset, Callback<List<Post>> callback);
}
```

Comment: What does the Post class look like? The error is pretty simple really, gson is expecting an array for a variable but is finding a single object instead.

Comment: @biglio23 it would help to see what is wrong if you show the json response and your pojos

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the request is returning an Json Object rather than a Json Array. Make sure the server is actually returning a list of Post, and that your Post object does not expect named fields as arrays when the Post from the server contains plain objects that use the same name.

Answer (score 0):

the problem on this : Callback> callback

Please create one more DAO on your daogenerator called DataPost then on your callback, change it to Callback callback.

then inside the DataPost Model add ToMany.

```
@ToMany
@JoinEntity(entity = Post.class, sourceProperty = "id", targetProperty = "id")
public List<Post> yourPropertyNamefromJSON; //--> to make the name it has to be the same as the JSON response for example : 

JSON RESPONSE

{
  "success": true,
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "blah",
      "description": "blah"
    }]
 }


 public List<Post> data; //--> name have to be data
```

if your mind ask this question : Why it needs 1 more class??? 
ANSWER: because your JSON start with "{" (Curly Bracket) that is not an array but it start with OBJECT.

This should solved your problem!!

GOOD LUCK!

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This is a very old question :D I don't use anymore this library. Anyway your answer can be helpful to other people.